# Displaying a user input in an html tag from the other file [HTML+JS]

Tags: javascript, html, input, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am sort of building an electron app using HTML, JS and CSS - just a basic thing.
I have two html files (say **FILE1.html** and **FILE2.html**).

In **file1** a user provides his username/password pair, which then takes him to **file2**.

What I want to do is to capture user's input (`username` specifically) in **file1** and display it in **file2**.

Now, I can do that within a single file; here is my code:

**FILE1**

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="username" /><br>   
    <button onclick="getUserName(); return false;">Continue</button>
  <h1 id="receivedUserName"></h1>
</body>
```

and JS file:

```
const getUserName = () => {
  let userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
  document.getElementById('receivedUserName').innerHTML = userName;
};
```

All works fine within file1 but what I actually need is to pass the captured `username` to the FILE2.

**FILE2**

```
<form>
  <span id="receivedUserName"></span>
</form>
```

Just cannot think of a way to go around it ...
Surely the line `<h1 id="receivedUserName"></h1>` in file1 is for for a single file testing.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use either GET-parameters, or store the information in the localStorage, and retrieve it from file2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localStorage something like the below (I haven't tested this):

```
let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
localStorage.setItem('username', username);
```

Then in the other file:

```
let username = localStorage.getItem('username');
document.getElementById('receivedUserName').innerText = username;
```

**VERY IMPORTANT SIDE NOTE:** you must use `innerText`, not `innerHTML` to set the contents of the `receivedUserName` element, in case the username contains a `<` or `&`. This is not just an aesthetic thing - it will cause the app to break badly, and if ever show data from one user to another user this way, you have a huge security hole as they could put malicious script in a script tag in their username. Google XSS or Cross site scripting.

Comment: I am building a prototype of an client-side electron app where I need to simulate a response form a server that the user has been authenticated to proceed. In production, after hitting Sign-In in the file1, the user is authenticated and the response comes to the file2 from the server.